# Exporting HTML to Word

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, export

I need to export some HTML to Word and came across this link:
https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-to-word-doc-docx-using-javascript

The code is as follows. It produces a .doc file (the old Word format) but I would prefer .docx. The article says that can be done with minor modification, but doesn't say how. Does anyone know how to make this change?

```
function Export2Doc(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Comment: Did you try just changing `filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc` to `filename?filename+'.docx':'document.doc`?

Comment: Yes, and that made no difference. I found out that this actually just produces an HTML file with some Word-specific headers, not an actual .doc file. I realized that if it is possible to produce an actual .doc/.docx file from HTML it would take a lot more code than this!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url 'data' to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing`. Untested.

Other changes might be needed. Google 'docx mime type'.